# What are the best keyboard macros for programming in windows?

Tags: keyboard, macros, performance

I like putting shortcuts of the form "g - google.lnk" in my start menu so google is two keystrokes away. Win, g.

My eight or so most frequent applications go there.

I also make links to my solution files I am always opening "x - Popular Project.lnk"

Are there any better ways to automate opening frequently used applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a reasonably good program for implementing windows key shortcuts.  You might instead define WIN + G to be "open browser to google" which gives you a better response time (don't have to wait for start menu to popup, etc)

There are macro programs that change the macros used based on the window that's in focus.  I've never needed that much control, but you might want to look into that.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

Get a keyboard launcher program like [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/)

Answer (score 0):

For shortcuts I use **Launchy**

For macros I use **AutoHotKey**

Others will suggest **SlickRun** for shortcuts also.

Answer (score 0):

I use a lot the "intellisense" snippets in Visual Studio. You can include your own snippets and press double tab when they appear in the list. That's definitely a time saver.

Answer (score 0):

I use [QuickMacros](http://www.quickmacros.com) and love it.

so much so, that I did some extensive training articles on it [here](http://www.TheMacroHook.blogspot.com).

Comment: six more years and still loving it.

Answer (score 0):

The holy grail- 
Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V

I kid, I kid! Try the veal!